# How to Auto rerun failed session in Informatica

Tags: informatica

I am using Informatica and I want to auto run the failed session. How can I achieve this?
I tried it by enabling Auto recover terminated task property in workflow. But it is not working. It is not being rerun on failure. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such out-of-the box feature. But there can be many solutions:

1. Ideally you'd use a separate tool / script to run the workflow, check it's state and re-run if failed. This can be achieved using second workflow with a command task, for example, but:
2. Why don't you try to resolve all the issues and make sure the workflow runs successfully?
3. Yet another option would be to have a touch command executed in case any session in the workflow fails, and have a second continuously running workflow with event-wait that executes the first workflow if the specified file shows up.